# Draw a line between lines which ends lie on the same x coordinate

Tags: python, image, opencv, matplotlib, image-processing

I have png files with lines as masks on grascale pngs. I need to connect ONLY the lines which ends lie on the same coordinate. So the connecting line would be vertical. I also want to have some tolerance here, lets say +/- 5 pixels.

Considering the simple example below. I would like to connect the thinner lines ONLY with only one additional line which would be vertical. I do not want to connect the thicker line.

[image: Lines like here]

Code to draw the lines:

```
def lines():
    img = np.zeros((256,256,1), dtype=np.uint8)
    img = cv2.line(img, (50,50), (128 ,128), color=(255), thickness=1)
    img = cv2.line(img, (128 ,200), (240 ,250), color=(255), thickness=1)
    img = cv2.line(img, (96 ,54), (150,164), color=(255), thickness=2)
```

So far I have something like this. For connecting dots only.

```
def dots():
    img = np.zeros((256,256,1), dtype=np.uint8)
    img = cv2.circle(img, (50,50), color=(255), radius=0, thickness=-1)
    img = cv2.circle(img, (128 ,200), color=(255), radius=0, thickness=-1)
    img = cv2.circle(img, (128 ,54), color=(255), radius=0, thickness=-1)

def connect_dots():
    img = dots()
    xy = np.argwhere(img == 255)
    x = xy == xy[:,1]
    x = np.argwhere(x[:,1] == True)
    x = xy[x]
    x = np.swapaxes(x, 1, 2)
    x = x[:,:2,:2]

    return x

def draw_line():
    img  = dots()
    start = np.flip(np.squeeze(connect_dots()[0,:,], axis=-1))
    end = np.flip(np.squeeze(connect_dots()[1,:,], axis=-1))
    print(start.shape, end)
    img = cv2.line(img, start, end, color=(177), thickness=1)
    cv2.imshow("connected lines", img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

But:

1. I feel like is a total spaghetti
2. It works only for dots not for lines
3. There is no tolerance, the point have to be exactly on the same x coordinate and the drawn line has to be exactly vertical.

[image: dots only]
[image: connected dots]

Comment: Get Canny edges. Then do HoughLinesP to get the lines. Then get the  end points. Then search for endpoints with close X values and connect them.

Answer (score 0):

- detect the endpoints of the lines (they have neighbors on one side but not the other).
- sort the endpoints by abscissa.
- scan the list of endpoints to detect those that are less than 5 pixels apart (unless they are endpoints of the same segment).